# how to change a function in existing 3rd party library in python

Tags: python

This was an interview question which was asked to me. Please do not penalize me if it doesn't make sense. She asked:

"I have an existing 3rd party lib in python and there is a function foo() in it. How do I modify that function after importing in my existing module?"

Comment: Off the top of my head, use a wrapper function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is called monkey-patching. In short, you can just assign to the variable holding the function:

```
import existingmodule

existingmodule.foo = lambda *args, **kwargs: "You fail it"
```

This is rarely the right answer in practice. It's much better to wrap something with your own function, or provide your own implementation elsewhere, or use inheritance (if a method on a class).

The only reason to do this is if you need the altered behaviour to be reflected in the library's own code (or other third party code); if so, test well. It's usually a better approach than just creating your own fork; that said, it might be a good idea to submit your code as a patch, so it's not just you supporting it if it is accepted by the project.

Answer (score 4):

The most common approach would be [Monkey patching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) (See: [stackoverflow: what is monkey patching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-monkey-patching))

For example:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.listdir('.')
['file_a', 'file_b']
>>> os.listdir = lambda folder: ['nothing in here, nope!']
>>> os.listdir('.')
['nothing in here, nope!']
```

There was a very good [talk](https://us.pycon.org/2012/schedule/presentation/380/) on the subject at PyCon 2012 that you can watch on [youtube](http://youtu.be/Adr_QuDZxuM)

The talk also gives a very good example of where monkey patching can be useful:
Say you have a third party library that does a certain thing. To do it's deed, this script demands to be run as root - but the actual functionality does not require root privileges. Now the third party library might be checking this with `os.geteuid() == 0`. 
By monkey patching in your code that uses this library you can override `geteuid` to fake being root to workaround this limitation.

Using monkey patching is a great way to do a quick fix to a library. Filing a bug report and waiting for a patch might take a while, so you can help yourself this way, without digging into the library source code.

Comment: It's not "a great way" to do anything. It's sometimes the only, or the least convoluted way to do something.