# Pydub The system can not find the file specified

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pydub

So here is my code :

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
sound1 = AudioSegment.from_mp3("sound_0.mp3")
sound2 = AudioSegment.from_mp3("sound_1.mp3")

sound = sound1 + sound2
sound.export("test.mp3",format="mp3")
```

Problem :
I got the error message : WindowsError: [Error 2] The system can not find the file specified

System configuration
Python version: 3.8
Pydub version: I just installed it
ffmpeg or avlib?: ffmpeg
ffmpeg/avlib version: 2020-12-15-git-32586a42da-full_build-www.gyan.dev

What did I try ?
So, I found some things to do on a [Stackoverflow subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22284461/pydub-windowserror-error-2-the-system-can-not-find-the-file-specified),
I tried to add this

```
pydub.AudioSegment.ffmpeg = "way//to//ffmpeg.exe"
```

But it doesn't worked, then this

```
AudioSegment.converter = "way//to//ffmpeg.exe"
```

Still doesn't work, so, because I'm on spyder with anaconda, I tried this on the anaconda prompt

```
conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg
```

I even tried to put ffmpeg.exe,ffplay.exe in the current working directory but still doesn't worked..

So I'm desperately here for some help, thanks in advance

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (notcomment) as text (not screenshot).There are othr useful information.

Comment: you didn't show full error message so it is not clear if you have problem with `.exe` files or with `.mp3` files. Maybe all your problem is `/full/path/to/sound_0.mp3`

Comment: if you think it is problem with `ffmpeg.exe` then you should open `cmd.exe` and check if works `C:/full/path/to/ffmpeg.exe`

Comment: This answer might be useful for you too. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76906056/15863196

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this same issue by putting `ffprobe.exe` in the current working directory, or replacing a function within pydub's utils by using [monkey patching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429547/how-to-change-a-function-in-existing-3rd-party-library-in-python) with `pydub.utils.get_prober_name = lambda: 'path/to/ffprobe.exe'` but that may not work for you